# UILocalnotification in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I had used `UNUserNotification` framework for iOS10
its working perfect BUT when I Run code in iOS9 Device is crash. Error is:

> UNUSernotification not found

What can be done to fix this error?

Comment: The `UNUserNotification` does not exist for iOS 9. You need to use `if #available(iOS 10, *)` for your `UNUserNotification` code. In the else clause you should write the equivalent code for iOS 9 without `UNUserNotification`

Comment: I have all ready try if #available(iOS 10.0, *) this one but my issue is How to manage framework compilation time "import UserNotifications" ??